# Set a models user field to the current logged in user before saving its django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

i  have a model form as so below

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        exclude = ('date_added', 'date_modified','owner','status','tags','slug','winning_tech','completiondate')
```

The owner field is a foreignKey linked to the Django User model and it's excluded from being rendered in the form.
I am trying to set the owner field to the current logged in user before i save the form.
My save function is contained in the following code.

```
def createJob(request):
  bix_user=getBixUser(request.user)
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = JobForm(request.POST)
      form.fields['owner']=bix_user
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()

      return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
 else:
        ....
```

I am very sure that i am doing the wrong thing.
I have not been in touch with my django side for a while so i would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always overwrite the `save()` method and add a user to it.

Something like this:

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, user, commit=True):
        job = ModelForm.save(commit=False)
        job.owner = user
        if commit:
            job.save()
        return job
```

Comment: Thanks, that's neater and it reduces the clutter in the view function

Answer (score 0):

So answered my own question, use commit=false and modify whatever values you want.
This code section draws in ideas from the two previous answers( wolPh and user*** )

```
def save(self,user, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
```

job = super(JobForm, self).save(commit=False,*args, **kwargs)
    job.owner = user
    if commit:
        job.save()
    return job

Answer (score 0):

I use a variation on WoLph above:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # add defaut owner field if not already stated

    if 'owner' not in self.__dict__:
        self.creator = system_user()

    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i am using a ModelForm, so i don't think i can access the owner field directly. The owner field is also excluded from the form.