# is system_user() defined in django?

Tags: django, photologue

My original question was actually how to add a User foreign key to Photolog type class (that uses Imagekit)

I see an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425150/set-a-models-user-field-to-the-current-logged-in-user-before-saving-its-django-mo/4428212#4428212), but when I tried to implement it, I get `global name 'system_user' is not defined`

I'm not surprised by that, but I am surprised that though it's in an answer, I can't find a reference to `system_user` in django docs.

(It's not on docs.djangoproject.com, and Google for django+system_user returns nothing interesting.)

I have this in the `class Photo` in Photologue models.py

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.title_slug is None:
        self.title_slug = slugify(self.title)
    if 'owner' not in self.__dict__:
         self.owner = system_user()               # this line fails
    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How should I import `system_user()`, or what can I use here instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `system_user` is not a django function. You should take all code snippets as pseudo code -- he's just saying "a function that returns my object".

`grep -ri "system_user" /path/to/django` returns nothing, so it doesn't exist in the django source.

Check out the accepted answer in the question you linked to, he overrides the save method, passes in the user object, and manually associates the object to the user.

In your case, since you're using a model, you'd have to pass in the user object to the model `save()` method.

```
# models
    def save(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.title_slug is None:
            self.title_slug = slugify(self.title)
        if user:
            self.owner = user
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# usage in view
myobj.save(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks also for the suggestion to use grep to search!

Comment: No prob! grepping the source is a fantastic tool when the amazing docs don't cover it.